# C++ Алгоритм std::partition_point для трех и более групп

Tags: c++, алгоритм, stl

Изучаю алгоритмы из стандартной библиотеки и не смог найти информацию по данному вопросу.
Например код взят от [сюда](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition_point):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 9> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    auto is_even = [](int i){ return i % 2 == 0; };
    std::partition(v.begin(), v.end(), is_even);

    auto p = std::partition_point(v.begin(), v.end(), is_even);

    std::cout << "Before partition:\n    ";
    std::copy(v.begin(), p, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << "\nAfter partition:\n    ";
    std::copy(p, v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

Итератор p указывает на элемент из массива, который был разбит по какому то признаку (за это отвечает функция, по нему разбивающая), но если эта функция разбивает элементы не на два подмножества, а, например, на три, на пять, на десять, вообще на хоть сколько, но заранее не известно, на сколько, то можно ли как - нибудь получить массив итераторов, указывающих на начало этих групп, используя алгоритмы STL?

Comment: я думаю, что вам нужен `map`/`unordered_map`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Стоп-стоп! `partition()` разбивает на **2** группы, и не более того. Потому что предикат разбиения возвращает либо `true`, либо `false`. Может, на одну :) - если для всех элементов предикат возвращает одно и то же значение.

Ну, а `partition_point` просто возвращает эту точку разбиения - может, вы разбивали как-то иначе и теперь не знаете, где там граница :)...

Если диапазон корректно не разделен - то возвращает итератор первого элемента, не удовлетворяющего предикату.

Если вы хотите разбивать как-то иначе ("*например, на три, на пять, на десять*") - то `partition` вам не поможет.

**Update**

Хотя... поможет, если применять предикаты так, чтобы последующие части не включали первую. Вот разбиение чисел на диапазоны до 5, от 5 до 10, от 10 до 15, 15 и выше.

```
vector<int> z;
for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) z.push_back(rand()%20);
auto p = partition(z.begin(),z.end(),[](int x) { return x < 5; });
p = partition(p,z.end(),[](int x) { return x < 10; });
p = partition(p,z.end(),[](int x) { return x < 15; });

for(int i: z) cout << setw(3) << i;
cout << endl;
```

И тогда `partition_point` будет возвращать точку разделения для соответствующего предиката..

По времени - быстрее сортировки даже при таком мелком объеме, как 1000 элементов: https://ideone.com/IMOjMz

Answer (score 0):

Стандартные алгоритмы являются часто используемыми, а вариант, прозвучавший в вашем вопросе(алгоритм, который вернет последовательность итераторов), может пригодится лишь очень редко и, может быть, только  для эксперимента. Поэтому такого алгоритма нет в стандарте, но те, что есть, помогут вам получить желаемое.

**Сортировка сама по себе и является разделением последовательности на несколько групп.** После сортировки, останется лишь получать итераторы, указывающие на элементы, отличавшиеся от предыдущего по предикату. Например разделим вектор строк по размерам строк:

```
std::vector<std::string> 
    v{"12", "23", "123", "1234", "234", "12345", "2345", "23456" };
using S = std::string_view;
auto pred = [](S s1, S s2) {return s1.size() < s2.size(); };
//сортировка по размерам
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), pred);
// можем смотреть отсортированный вектор
auto Out = std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " ");
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), Out);
//теперь нужно получит вектор итераторов,
//разделяющие последовательность строк по размеру 
//ложим в вектор итераторы на элементы,
//разделенные(при сортировке) по предикату
auto first = v.begin(), second = first + 1; 
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>::iterator> Iters{ first };
for (; second != v.end(); ++second, ++first) {        
    if (pred(*first, *second))
        Iters.push_back(second);        
}
//просмотр результата
for (auto& It : Iters)
    cout << '\n'  << It - v.begin();
```

Comment: Только надо отдавать себе отчет в том, что сортировка - O(N log N), а через `partition` - O(N*(M-1)), где M - число частей...

Comment: @Harry, ну да, поэтому, если нужно разделять на две группы, то лучше  partition

Comment: Можно и не на две - см. дополнение в моем ответе.

Comment: Можно, но тут еще разобраться нужно, чем лучше несколько вызовов  partition одного вызова sort

Comment: Вот [результат разборок](https://ideone.com/IMOjMz). Даже при 1000 элементов разбиение на 4 части быстрее.